# Extract duplicate values with number of occurrences for JS Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

For example we have an array

```
const nums = [1,1,8,12,2,3,3,3,7];
```

If I want to map number of occurrences of each array member I could use something like

```
function extractDupes(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function (acc, item) { 
    if (item in acc) {
      acc[item]++
    }
    else {
      acc[item] = 1
    }
    return acc
  }, {})
}
```

This would return object like

```
{ '1': 2, '2': 1, '3': 3, '7': 1, '8': 1, '12': 1 }
```

Is there an optimal way to filter out numbers which are showing up more than once just with using reduce (in a single pass) and have just

```
{ '1': 2, '3': 3 }
```

Comment: I would sort the array and compare values. I have this solved somewhere, let me see if I can find it

Comment: have a staging variable for values equaling 1 and promote them to the main result when they're hit the second time?

Comment: I think the resulting code you choose to use should depend on the size of your inputs. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const nums = [1,1,8,12,2,3,3,3,7];
const dups = {};
nums.forEach((v, i, s) => {
  if (s.indexOf(v) != i)
    if (dups[v])
      dups[v]++;
    else
      dups[v] = 2;
});

console.log(dups);
```

If you also want the array of unique values at the end:

```js
const nums = [1,1,8,12,2,3,3,3,7];
const dups = {};
const uniques = nums.filter((v, i, s) => {
  if (s.indexOf(v) != i)
    if (dups[v])
      dups[v]++;
    else
      dups[v] = 2;
  else
    return true;
});

console.log(dups);
console.log(uniques);
```

Comment: I think OP specifically asked for the solution to the problem with `reduce` method.

Comment: @Yousaf Yes, but I think their main concern was with the "in a single pass" part. `reduce`  would actually aggregate no value to this solution because the final object already exists since the very first loop. What we do is just change their content.

Answer (score 1):

have a staging variable for values equaling 1 and promote them to the main result when they're hit the second time?

```js
const nums = [1,1,8,12,2,3,3,3,7];

function extractDupes(arr) {
  const staging = {}
  return arr.reduce(function (acc, item) { 
    if (item in acc) {
      acc[item]++
    } else if(item in staging) {
      acc[item] = 2
      delete staging[item]
    } else {
      staging[item] = 1
    }
    return acc
  }, {})
}

document.getElementById('hi').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(extractDupes(nums))
```

```html
<div id="hi"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take a nested property for the final object.

```js
function extractDupes(array) {
    return array
        .reduce(function(acc, item) {
            if (acc[item]) acc.dupes[item] = (acc.dupes[item] || 1) + 1;
            else acc[item] = true;
            return acc;
         }, { dupes: {} })
        .dupes;
}

const nums = [1, 1, 8, 12, 2, 3, 3, 3, 7];

console.log(extractDupes(nums))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Object.entries` to transform the object to key-value pairs then filter the pair that have value greater than 1, and then transform the pairs back to object by `Object.fromEntries`

```js
const nums = [1, 1, 8, 12, 2, 3, 3, 3, 7]

function extractDupes(arr) {
  return Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(
      arr.reduce(function (acc, item) {
        if (item in acc) {
          acc[item]++
        } else {
          acc[item] = 1
        }
        return acc
      }, {})
    ).filter(([key, value]) => value > 1)
  )
}

console.log(extractDupes(nums))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let arrAssist = [];

array.sort();
arrAssist.push(inventory[0]);
for(var i = 1; i < array.length; i++){
  if(array[i] != array[i - 1]){
    arrAssist.push(array[i]);
  }
}
```

in this example, `arrAssist` contains the array with no duplicates

Answer (score 0):

It has been answered and accepted but anyhow here is how i would do.

```js
const nums = [1, 1, 8, 12, 2, 3, 3, 3, 7];

const map = nums.reduce((acc, num) => {
  acc.frequency[num] = (acc.frequency[num] || 0) + 1;

  if (acc.frequency[num] > 1) {
    acc.replicates[num] = acc.frequency[num];
  }

  return acc;
}, { frequency: {}, replicates: {} });

console.log(map);
```